# "No message available" using Spring Boot/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf and I'm trying to access a simple webpage.
I don't have any error when building the project. Only this one when accessing `localhost:8080/greeting` :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Dec 02 15:36:04 CET 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I have a controller :

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String user(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name",name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

A main:

```
package boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.themyleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/> 
<title>SecondMaven</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, '+ ${name} + '!!!!!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I don't have any clue of what is wrong with my code. I think that it is a configuration problem, but so far I didn't get any luck.
I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Where did you put your `greeting.html`?

Comment: In src/main/resources/templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your main application entry:

```
package boot;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// imports

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application { ... }
```

The `package boot` along with a `@SpringBootApplication` means that only components in or under `boot` package will be scanned and registered in the application context. Here is how your controller looks like:

```
package controller;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// imports

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String user(...) { ... }
}
```

Since it resides in the `controller` package, it can't be scanned by the `@SpringBootApplication`, hence it's not going to be registered and won't handle requests to the `/greeting` endpoint.

The easiest solution is to move your controllers (and other to be scanned components) under the `boot` package, e.g. `boot.controller` in your particular case.

Anyway, Spring Boot does not require any specific code layout to work, however, there are some best practices that help. You can checkout those best practices [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public ModelAndView user(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new ModelAndView("greeting").addObject("name", name);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/web-programming-examples/tree/master/spring-mvc-hello-world) you have an equivalent running example.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem. I was not using `@SpringBootApplication` properly.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall having issues with self closing tags in my limited experience with Thymeleaf. Try manually closing the elements, for example

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
```

instead of

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
```